# How to in C# keep a set number of letters for a string in console writeline

Tags: c#, console.writeline

Ok so basically I want something like

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "{0}:   {1}/{2}hp    {3}/{4}mp   {5}", 
    character.Identifier, 
    character.CurrentHealth, 
    character.MaxHealth,
    character.CurrentMagic, 
    character.MaxMagic, 
    character.Fatigue
    );
```

and then have the character.Identifier (which is basically a name) have a set number of letters which it will replace with spaces if needed so that in might print

```
Josh:   20/20hp    20/20mp   3
```

or

```
J:      20/20hp    20/20mp   3
```

but the HP and then mp and everything else is always in line.
I am aware that its probably one of the {0:} but i couldn't figure out one that works

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/txafckwd.aspx <-- MSDN guide to using .NET Formatting based functions (String.Format, Console.WriteLine, etc.)

Comment: did you tried ***String.Format*** ? _not marked answer_ ***yet***

Answer (score 7):

The second argument in the `{0}` notation can give you a fixed width field, so if you wanted the identifier (name) to always be 10 characters long and be left justified, you would use `{0,-10}`

MSDN is a good resource for this kind of question too, if you read the documentation for [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) it has an example of a fixed width table that might be similar to what you want.

Also, as Hogan's answer correctly points out, you would have to append the `:` to the string outside of the format string if you want it right next to the name.

Comment: that didn't work :S 
Console.WriteLine("{0,15}:   {1}/{2}hp    {3}/{4}mp   {5}", character.Identifier, character.CurrentHealth, character.MaxHealth,
 character.CurrentMagic, character.MaxMagic, character.Fatigue);
Console.WriteLine("********************************");

Comment: @bed - the issue is the `:` -- see my answer.  Also, you left justify with a negative number not right justify it.

Answer (score 5):

You can right pad a string with spaces by using:

```
character.Identifier.PadRight(10);
```

This should give you the format you are after.

Comment: Best answer IMO!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
const int colWidth = 10;
Console.WriteLine("{0,-"+colWidth.ToString()+"}{1,-"+colWidth.ToString()+"}{2,-"+colWidth.ToString()+"}{3}", 
    (character.Identifier+":").PadRight(colWidth+1).Remove(0,colWidth),
    (character.CurrentHealth+"/"+character.MaxHealth+"hp").PadRight(colWidth+1).Remove(0,colWidth),
    (character.CurrentMagic+"/"+character.MaxMagic+"mp").PadRight(colWidth+1).Remove(0,colWidth),
    (character.Fatigue,colWidth));
```

This will add spaces to the end of string and then truncate the result.
See the docs for String.Format

**NOTES**

I append the `:` to the name outside of the format string and I "merge" the hp and mp sections and then put them in a column.

Comment: Have you ever test with the name longer than length of format specified, like "**Josh0123456789**" ?

Comment: @KenKin - I don't have to test, I know what format does with a specifier like `{0,-10}`, it will truncate it.

Comment: Actually format like `{0,-10}` won't do truncate. I don't consider right-aligned as bug. In fact, I tested both alignment, and I believe anchor the colons in a fixed position is reasonable.

Comment: @KenKin - good point -- fixed that and added a col width constant.